# How to release multiple versions of app for testing at the same time - Google Play Console?

Tags: android, testing, google-play, devops, google-play-console

As per our issue management we are developing multiple issues at same time.

We are planing to release all the issues for testing at same time in play store.

Is there any way to publish mulitple seperate versions of app in same time for testing?

Comment: Why do you need it to be on Google Play?
Do you want to do Open or Close testing?

Comment: Closed testing.

Answer (score 0):

You can release multiple .apk test builds in Google Play **internal (not closed) testing**, learn the difference [here](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9845334?hl=en). Testers will access a build via a protected link only accessible to licensed internal testers of your app. Following different links testers will access different builds.

To enable internal testing, developers:

1. follow the [instructions](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6062777) from Google,
2. distribute .apk test builds through Google Play [internal app sharing](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9844679?hl=en)
3. configure the [licensed testers](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9845334?sjid=14604519620997563577-EU&visit_id=638339131880154718-2760007971&rd=1#closed_beta&zippy=%2Cclosed-test-manage-testers-by-email-address-or-google-groups%2Cclosed-test-manage-testers-by-organization%2Cinternal-test-manage-up-to-testers)' list of Google accounts

— a pretty standard procedure